# uninitialized constant Order::PAYMENT_TYPES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I first call an action in my in my Orders controller I get the following:

`uninitialized constant Order::PAYMENT_TYPES` and on refresh I get `undefined method 'key?' for nil:NilClass`.

This points to an error in my models code. I'm able to track it down to the following lines:

```
 validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES

  PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit Card", "Purchase Order"]
```

What am I doing wrong with my validates line?

I've also tried using `validates :pay_type, inclusion: {in: PAYMENT_TYPES}` as well and that didn't work.

Comment: Try `:inclusion => PAYMENT_TYPES`.

Comment: @MurifoX, that doesn't work (same results). And isn't that just another syntax for what I'm already doing?

Comment: Yeah, this new hash syntax sucks. Symbols with colon before and after are terrible to read.

Comment: Oh, I actually prefer. I guess to each his own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are defining your PAYMENT_TYPES constant after you are using it in your class. Reverse the order and it should be fine.

Comment: Worked, and that simple huh? Thanks.